# アーカイブから"mvpart"パッケージをダウンロードできません

Tags: r, windows-10, rstudio

いくつかのドキュメントを参考にしましたが、アーカイブから"mvpart"パッケージをダウンロードしようとすると下記の通りエラーになってしまいます。
両方ともunknown type name 'Sint'が原因のようですが、何のことだか見当がつきません。

ご教示いただけますと幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

### 試行したコード①

```
install.packages("C:/R/mvpart_1.6-2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

### 試行したコード②

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("cran/mvpart")
```

### 試行したコード③（コマンドウィンドウにて）

```
R CMD INSTALL mvpart_1.6-2.tar.gz
```

※これに関してはpathは変更したのにパッケージをそもそも認識できていない段階です。
※コマンドウィンドウにてRを立ち上げることはできています。

### 試行したコード①の出力結果

```
* installing *source* package 'mvpart' ...
** package 'mvpart' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
using C compiler: 'gcc.exe (GCC) 12.2.0'
gcc  -I"C:/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c anova.c -o anova.o
In file included from anova.c:6:
rpart.h:37:5: error: unknown type name 'Sint'
   37 |     Sint   *numcat;        /* variable type: 0=cont, 1+  =#categories */
      |     ^~~~
rpart.h:38:5: error: unknown type name 'Sint'
   38 |     Sint   **sorts;             /* allocated on the fly */
      |     ^~~~
make: *** [C:/R/R-43~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf:265: anova.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'mvpart'
* removing 'C:/R/R-4.3.1/library/mvpart'
Warning in install.packages :
   パッケージ ‘C:/R/mvpart_1.6-2.tar.gz’ のインストールは、ゼロでない終了値をもちました
```

Comment: こちらの記事が類似の状況かもしれません。[Renv fails to compile packages but install.packages() works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76375230/9014308) 他にはこんな記事が何か参考になるかも。[R本体とRStudioとRパッケージの インストール（Windows版）](https://www.iu.a.u-tokyo.ac.jp/textbook/R/R1.010_win.pdf)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。記事の通りダウングレードしてみたところ、別のエラーが吐き出されできませんでした・・・しかし、違うパソコンで同じ操作をしてみたところ、インストールできましたのできっと何らかの不具合があるのだと思います・・・とりあえず別のパソコンで処理しようと思います。ありがとうございました。

Comment: できれば情報共有のために、どのような対策を行ったかの環境構築・設定や詳細な手順を自己回答してみてください。